# running maven integration tests in multi process single threaded mode

Tags: java, maven, junit, multiprocessing

I would like to run my integration tests in parallel so that:
* each test method is run by a different jvm
* and each uses a single thread

After reading [the surefire docs](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html) I thought of using:

```
mvn test -DforkCount=2 -DreuseForks=false -Dparallel=methods -DthreadCount=1
```

but my tests appear to fail (of course, running just `mvn test` that runs them sequentially doesn't fail)

Any idea how I can achieve multi process single threaded?

Comment: Offtop: why do you need this?

Comment: I have some legacy code that I need to improve its performance.and some of it is not thread safe and my city is only 50% loaded.

Comment: First i would suggest to understand why they fail cause if those tests are unit tests they should work...Maybe you are doing not clean unit tests more integration tests...

Comment: @khmarbaise the tests are integration tests

Comment: This means using failsafe plugin instead of surefire....where you make a separate check of all integration tests and may be you need to fail the whole build...

Answer (score 1):

Surefire plugin executes different classes in `forkCount` separate JVM processes, each JVM using `threadCount` threads and if `parallel=methods` then each method will be given a thread. In other words each **fork** is given a class, each **method** is given a thread. You cannot map between **methods** and **forks**.

From the [Surefire's page, paragraph on combining forkCount and parallel](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html):

> However, you can use parallel=methods: classes are executed in forkCount concurrent processes, each of the processes can then use threadCount threads to execute the methods of one class in parallel.

**TestNG** has following annotation in case it could help:
`@Test(threadPoolSize = 3, invocationCount = 6, timeOut = 1000)`

EDIT: having just read the comments:
You have to make your unit tests correct first, and then speed the execution up.